# Interface with generic function

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a interface like:

```
 public interface ITableData
    {
        List<T> ListAll<T>() where T : TableData;
        void Insert(Object o);

    }
```

and my class implemented the interface:

```
  public class BookData:ITableData
        {
           public List<T> ListAll<T>() where T : TableData
            {
                //some code here
            }
        }
```

in fact, i want to have the result like this:

```
public class BookData:ITableData
{
  public List<Book> ListAll()
  { List<Book> bookList =XXXXXX;
//some code here
return bookList}
}
```

how to achieve that?
Thanks all.

Comment: Why did you tag this "templates"?

Comment: err, because i used Templates ?

Comment: They're not templates in C#, they're called generics. They look the same, but work in different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the generic argument to the interface instead of on the method:

```
public interface ITableData<T> where T : TableData
{
    List<T> ListAll();
    void Insert(Object o);
}

public class BookData : ITableData<Book>
{
    public List<Book> ListAll()
    {
        List<Book> bookList =XXXXXX;
        //some code here
        return bookList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs because

```
public List<Book>
```

is not a valid implementation of the interface method

```
List<T> ListAll<T>() where T : TableData
```

The reason for this is that your interface explicitly states that `T` can be any `TableData`. As your method only works for `Book` objects and not any `TableData` object, you get an error.

The solution is to implement a generic interface:

```
public interface ITableData<T> where T : TableData
// Implement your methods using T
```

that you can then implement in your class as such:

```
public class BookData:ITableData<Book>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to implement the List<T> function?

Comment: Just as you did in your example. In your interface you will work with type `T` and return a `List<T>`, and then in your code itself you simply substitute in a valid type for `T`.